# How to disable Table Design tab in Excel using OfficeJS

Tags: office-js

We have developed Excel add-in using officejs and below are the scenario hence kindly requesting you to help on the same.

**For Dekstop version**

1. When we click any of custom ribbon commands and once data binded into excel then new tab "Table Design" opened in Excel which do not want to open automatically.
2. Kindly suggest to disable the above said scenario. 
    Please find attached screen shot.

[image]

**For Online version**

For online Excel it is not opening automatically new tab "Table Design" which is the required scenario to expect to work in desktop version also.

**Sample Code used:**

```
var dtTable = new Office.TableData();
    dtTable.headers = ['Id', 'Name', 'DOB', 'year'];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      dtTable.rows.push([data[i].ID, data[i].Name, data[i].DOB, data[i].year]);
    }

    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(dtTable, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Table }, function (asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
      } else {

      }
    });
```

**TRIED BASED ON SUGGESTED ANSWER:**

```
 Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(dtTable, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Table }, function (asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
      } else {
        Office.context.document.goToByIdAsync("Sheet1", Office.GoToType.NamedItem, function (asyncResult) {
          if (asyncResult.status ==  Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
              // showMessage("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
          }
          else {
              // showMessage("Navigation successful");
          }
      });
        
      }
    });
```

**SECOND TIME:**

```
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(dtTable, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Table }, function (asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
      } else {
               
      }
    });            
    Office.context.document.goToByIdAsync("Sheet1", Office.GoToType.NamedItem, function (asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
          // showMessage("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
      }
      else {
          // showMessage("Navigation successful");
      }
  });
```

**SAMPLE TRIED ON 06-23-2020 AND ATTACHED SCREEN SHOT FOR THE VALUES**

```
async function getData(event: any) {
  await BindExcel();
  event.completed();
}


async function BindExcel() {    //testing for Table Desing tab
    Excel.run(async context => { 
    var table = new Office.TableData();
    table.headers = [['Header', 'Header2']];
    table.rows = [['Entry11', 'Entry12'], ['Entry21', 'Entry22'], ['Entry31', 'Entry33']];
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(table, {coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Table},
        function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                console.log(asyncResult.error.message);
            }
        });
        Office.context.document.goToByIdAsync("Sheet1", Office.GoToType.NamedItem); 
    return context.sync();
  })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add some details. Are these custom ribbon commands that are part of your add-in? Do they import data to the spreadsheet? Do they import the data to a table?

Comment: @rick.. Yes it's part of custom functions ribbon command......

Comment: @rick.. Any update please...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "custom functions ribbon command". A custom function is not launched from a ribbon command. Do the ribbon commands import data to the spreadsheet? Do they import the data to a table? –

Comment: @rick..  sorry for typo error...trying to confirm that those are part of custom ribbon commands implemented in excel....When i click any one of custom ribbon command once data got imported into spreadsheet then the "Table Design" appears as attached in previous screen shot....

Comment: OK. But is the range of cells that you are importing data into part of a table? Or is it just an ordinary range?

Comment: Yes Rick...I am using TableData()....I have attached sample code for binding data which have mentioned in main request and you can refer the same...

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this. It is standard behavior in Excel that the Table Design ribbon opens when any part of a table is selected. When you add data to a table, your code is also selecting the table, so the Table Design ribbon opens. If you don't want the Table Design ribbon open, you need to add a command that selects something outside of the table. I was able to do this by adding the following call of `setSelectedDataAsync`:

```
Office.context.document.goToByIdAsync("Sheet1", Office.GoToType.NamedItem);
```

Replace "Sheet1" with the name of your sheet. This will switch back to the Home ribbon.

Comment: Hi Rick.. Thanks for the solution.. I tried with same which i have mentioned on initial request. But still new Table Design tab appears...Hence kindly confirm any correction on the way i tried...

Comment: Find the ";" (semicolon) that ends the call of `setSelectedDataAsync`. Movw the call of `goToByIDAsync` to a line _after_ that ";".

Comment: Hi Rick... SECOND TIME I tried but still Table Design Tab appearing with that code.

Comment: Sorry. But I can't reproduce this. It works for me.

Comment: Hi Rick...I have attached FINAL SAMPLE CODE on which I was able to bind api data into excel sheet with new Table Design tab still opening....Do you have any sample code like the scenario with Table Data binding with Api without opening Table Design tab so that i can refer the same with entire code structure and trying to find where I am missing..

Comment: I used your code and added that line after the ";". So you have already tried the exact code that works for me. The ribbon switched to Table Design and then back to the Home ribbon so fast that I did not even see the Table Design ribbon open. Why don't you recreate the problem in the Script Lab tool and then export a gist. Tell me the URL of the gist and I'll try running it.

Comment: I am not sure about Script Lab but i can try very basic sample in typescript and confirm you with the scenario......

Comment: I have reproduced with sample data with screen shot. Can you let me know if anything to re-write the coding? It is not having any api call.

Comment: @rick...Have you had a chance looking into this?

Comment: Download the [Script Lab](https://appsource.microsoft.com/product/office/wa104380862) tool and see if you can reproduce the problem in Script Lab.

Comment: Sorry..again i dont know about the Script Lab tool and we are using VSCode with typescript dedicatedly.... so the sample code which i have updated recently is very basic code i tried using ExuecteFunction method..if possible with that same scenario to achieve do we have the working sample?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry..again i dont know about the Script Lab tool and we are using VSCode with typescript dedicatedly.... so the sample code which i have updated recently is very basic code i tried using ExuecteFunction method..if possible with that same scenario to achieve do we have the working sample?